# Directiva con conflicto en index.html

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

tengo el siguiente dilema, tengo en el index.html el llamado a una directiva llamada "loggin", cuando llamo la directiva en la etiqueta , las demás dejan de funcionar, cuando se lo quito, funciona normalmente, el problema es que necesito la directiva para que me muestre la pantalla del login y pueda verificar las credenciales

```
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/app.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/factoresController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/caracteristicasController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/indicadoresController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/programasController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/procesoAutoevaluacionController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/procesoAutoevaluacionInsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/autoevaluacionController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/autoevaluacionInsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/documentosProcesoController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/autoevaluacionDocumentosController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/informesAutoevaluacionController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/profesoresController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/estudiantesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/parametrosController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/maestrosProgramasController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/usuariosController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/valoracionController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/factoresInstitucionalesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/caracteristicasInstitucionalesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/indicadoresInstitucionalesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/autenticacionDirective.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/ingresoController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/factoresServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/caracteristicasServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/indicadoresServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/programasServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/autoevaluacionServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/autoevaluacionInsServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/autoevaluacionDocumentosServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/informesAutoevaluacionServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/profesoresServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/estudiantesServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/parametrosServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/usuariosService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/valoracionServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/factoresInstitucionalesServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/caracteristicasInstitucionalesServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./service/indicadoresInstitucionalesServices.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
  <loggin class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" showform2="showform" admin="vistadm" encuesta="vistaenc" evaluador="vistaeva" ng-show="showform"></loggin>
 <div ng-show="!showform">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
           <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
             <li>
               <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/encuestas" ng-show="vistaenc">Encuestas</a>
            </li>
                <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="false">
                    <uib-accordion-heading><p  class="nav-link" ng-show="vistadm">Parametros Autoevaluación</p></uib-accordion-heading>
                        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/parametros" ng-show="vistadm">Rangos de Calificaci&oacuten</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/programas" ng-show="vistadm">Programas</a>
                        </li>
                <!--    <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/maestrosProgramas/-1">Maestros Programas</a>
                        </li> -->   
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/factores" ng-show="vistadm">Factores Programas</a>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/caracteristicas" ng-show="vistadm">Caracteristicas Programas</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/indicadores" ng-show="vistadm">Aspectos Programas</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/factoresInstitucionales" ng-show="vistadm">Factores Institucionales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/caracteristicasInstitucionales" ng-show="vistadm" >Características Institucionales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/indicadoresInstitucionales" ng-show="vistadm">Aspectos Institucionales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/usuarios" ng-show="vistadm">Regristro de Usuario</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="false">
                    <uib-accordion-heading><p  class="nav-link" ng-show="vistaeva">Procesos de Autoevaluación</p></uib-accordion-heading>
                        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/procesoAutoevaluacion/-1" ng-show="vistaeva">Autoevaluación Programas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/procesoAutoevaluacionIns/-1" ng-show="vistaeva">Autoevauación Institucional</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/procesoPlanMejora/-1" ng-show="vistaeva">Plan de Mejoramiento Programas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" ng-href="#!/procesoPlanMejora/-1" ng-show="vistaeva">Plan de Mejoramiento Institucional</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                  
                </ul>
            </uib-accordion>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

está es la directiva

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.directive('loggin', function(){
    return{

        scope: {
            showform2: '=showform2',
            admin: '=admin',
            evaluador: '=evaluador',
            encuesta: '=encuesta'
        },
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'ingresoController'

    };
});
```

este es mi app.js el modulo donde redirecciono

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate','ngSanitize'])
.config(['$routeProvider',
       function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.
             when('/encuestas', {
                templateUrl: 'encuestas.html'
             }).
             when('/factores', {
                templateUrl: 'factores.html',
                controller: 'factoresController'
             }).
             when('/caracteristicas', {
                templateUrl: 'caracteristicas.html',
                controller: 'caracteristicasController'
             }).
             when('/indicadores', {
                templateUrl: 'indicadores.html',
                controller: 'indicadoresController'
             }).
             when('/programas', {
                templateUrl: 'programas.html',
                controller: 'programasController'
             }).
             when('/procesoAutoevaluacion/:procesoAutoevaluacionID', {
                    templateUrl: 'procesoAutoevaluacion.html',
                    controller: 'procesoAutoevaluacionController'
             }).
             when('/procesoAutoevaluacionIns/:procesoAutoevaluacionID', {
                    templateUrl: 'procesoAutoevaluacionIns.html',
                    controller: 'procesoAutoevaluacionInsController'
             }).
             when('/autoevaluacion/:autoevaluacionID', {
                 templateUrl: 'autoevaluacion.html',
                 controller: 'autoevaluacionController'
             }).
             when('/autoevaluacionIns/:autoevaluacionID', {
                 templateUrl: 'autoevaluacionIns.html',
                 controller: 'autoevaluacionInsController'
             }).
             when('/factoresInstitucionales', {
                 templateUrl: 'factoresInstitucionales.html',
                 controller: 'factoresInstitucionalesController'
             }).
             when('/caracteristicasInstitucionales', {
                 templateUrl: 'caracteristicasInstitucionales.html',
                 controller: 'caracteristicasInstitucionalesController'
             }).
             when('/indicadoresInstitucionales', {
                 templateUrl: 'indicadoresInstitucionales.html',
                 controller: 'indicadoresInstitucionalesController'
             }).
             when('/valorarCaracteristicas/:programaID', {
                 templateUrl: 'valorarCaracteristicas.html',
                 controller: 'valoracionController'
             }).
             when('/documentosAutoevaluacion/:autoevaluacionID', {
                 templateUrl: 'documentosAutoevaluacion.html',
                 controller: 'autoevaluacionDocumentosController'
             }).
             when('/informesAutoevaluacion/:autoevaluacionID', {
                 templateUrl: 'informesAutoevaluacion.html',
                 controller: 'informesAutoevaluacionController'
             }).
             when('/profesores/:programaID', {
                 templateUrl: 'profesores.html',
                 controller: 'profesoresController'
             }).
             when('/estudiantes/:programaID', {
                 templateUrl: 'estudiantes.html',
                 controller: 'estudiantesController'
             }).
             when('/parametros', {
                 templateUrl: 'parametros.html',
                 controller: 'parametrosController'
             }).
             when('/maestrosProgramas/:programaID', {
                 templateUrl: 'maestrosProgramas.html',
                 controller: 'maestrosProgramasController'
             }).
             when('/usuarios', {
                    templateUrl: 'usuarios.html',
                    controller: 'usuariosController'
             });
}]);
```

este es mi ingresoController, donde valido las credenciales

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("ingresoController", ['usuariosServices','$scope', '$rootScope', function(usuariosServices,$scope, $rootScope){

        $scope.showform2 = true;
        $scope.admin = false;
        $scope.encuesta = false;
        $scope.evaluador = false;


        $scope.ingresar = function(usuarioingreso,contrasenaingreso) {
            usuariosServices.listarUsuarios().then(function (response){
                $scope.usuarios = response.data;
                $scope.usuarios.forEach(function (usuario,index){
                    if(usuario.cedula == usuarioingreso){
                        if(usuario.contrasena == contrasenaingreso){
                            $scope.showform2=false;
                            if(usuario.rol == "Admin"){
                                $scope.admin=true;
                                $scope.encuesta = true;
                                $scope.evaluador = true;
                            }else
                                if (usuario.rol != "Admin"){
                                    $scope.encuesta = true;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                })

            })

    }
```

Quisiera saber si hay algo que esté mal dentro de la directiva, ya que cuando la nombro en el index, me genera conflictos.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un app nueva que sea solo de login y que después te redireccione a lo demás, es mala practica tener todo en el mismo html, para validar credenciales tendrás que hacerlo en cada petición que realices una vez logeado.